# Python Matplotlib X-axis label dual axis with dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've got a dual axis bar and line plot using matplotlib. I read the data in as a dataframe,

```
[WEEK       SIGNUPS APPLICATIONS    PRECOURSE_WORK  QUALIFIED   ENROLLED    SPEND
 2019-10-07 5674    2938            2220            106         2           77581.67
 2019-10-14 4538    2225            2309            567         204         61258.08
 2019-10-21 3865    1997            1801            121         39          53700.58
 2019-10-28 3559    1886            1641            162         39          53543.28
 2019-11-04 3782    1946            1980            190         109         49495.64
 2019-11-11 4033    2035            1568            118         109         49952.17
 2019-11-18 3999    2009            1537            83          77          58545.72
 2019-11-25 6170    3322            1660            110         61          52332.4
 2019-12-02 5189    2658            7041            73          30          56727.55
 2019-12-09 4631    2497            7904            174         116         60977.49
 2019-12-16 4935    2501            3492            108         82          68179.54
 2019-12-23 5289    2603            1983            80          38          76956.81
 2019-12-30 5843    3037            2150            90          80          76246.14
 2020-01-06 4194    1930            1619            74          57          46114.68]
```

My code works and produces a graph (below)
[image: Dual Axis spend graph]

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
from matplotlib import style
style.use('seaborn-paper')
#print(plt.style.available)
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20, 10
#plt.xticks(df[['WEEK']])
ax = df[['SPEND']].plot(kind='bar', color = 'lightblue')
ax.set_ylabel("Spend",color="blue",fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel('Weeks',color="blue",fontsize=20)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df[['SIGNUPS','APPLICATIONS','ENROLLED']].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=4.0)
fmt = '${x:,.0f}'
tick = mtick.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick)
```

When I uncomment the line `plt.xticks(df[['WEEK']])` I get the following error

> ConversionError Failed to convert value(s) to axis unit.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you want the xticks to look like?

Comment: Hi William - I want them to say Be the values in the first column in df, the weeks listed.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the approach in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

[`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) is expecting the tick locations to be specified and optionally the labels, from the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) the signature is

> ```
> xticks(ticks, [labels], **kwargs)
> ```

So when you do

```py
plt.xticks(df[['WEEK']])
```

It is trying to interpret the dates in the `'WEEK'` column as the locations for the ticks. What you want to do instead is use [`plt.set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) which expects only the labels be specified, i.e.

```py
plt.set_xticklabels(df[['WEEK']])
# or
plt.set_xticklabels(df[['WEEK']].values)
```

Although you may also need to manually covert the `values` to strings, depending on how they are defined.

Comment: Hi William - Thanks for the help. I wasn't able to get the solution you provided to work, so I imported numpy and then added
         
         import numpy as np
         week = df['WEEK']
         pos = np.arange(len(week))
         plt.xticks(pos, week)

I have no doubt yours would have worked, but I am very bad at Python and had to import another library. I think you are correct in that I needed to convert my weeks to strings in order to get it to work. Thank you for all the help, though!

Comment: @MatthewIngle If you don’t mind my asking, what was the problem you encountered with this approach? Just out of curiosity